# Citrix ica not downloading anymore

Tags: download, plugins, citrix

My employer has a Citrix ica icon available, which launches a remote desktop client within Citrix.  The ica used to download (1 week ago), but now it is not.  What would possibly cause the ica file not to download?  I'm using the same machine that I know worked before.

update:

Okay, after uninstalling Citrix, and re-installing, I get this:

[image]

"Citrix online plug-in Configuration Manager: No value could be found for (ClientHostedApps) that satisfies all lockdown requirements.  The lockdown requirements in force may be conflicting."

Comment: found this, but didn't fix it http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX132875

Comment: http://forums.citrix.com/thread.jspa?threadID=300487

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with my employer's Citrix Receiver download.

**To fix:**

Remove the ClientHostedApps registry key using the Windows registry editor.  http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX132875  Then uninstall the Citrix Receiver.  Then re-install the Citrix Receiver by downloading it from the Citrix site.  http://receiver.citrix.com/

This only happens if you install the Citrix Receiver using Google Chrome, and on Windows 7.